# Re-create zip file from another zip file

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-ziparchive

Given a zip file, I need to re-create it with a specified compression level (eg, no compression).

I'm nearly there, but get the error:

> Failed: Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.

If I save the recreated zip file to windows, it looks like it's correct (correct file size, entries all exist with correct file sizes) but none of the files are extractable.

```
public static byte[] ReCompress(byte[] originalArchive, CompressionLevel newCompressionLevel)
{
    var entries = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();

    ///////////////////////////
    // STEP 1: EXTRACT ALL FILES
    ///////////////////////////
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(originalArchive))
    using (var originalZip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        foreach (var entry in originalZip.Entries)
        {
            var isFolder = entry.FullName.EndsWith("/");
            if (!isFolder)
            {
                using (var stream = entry.Open())
                using (var entryMS = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(entryMS);
                    entries.Add(entry.FullName, entryMS.ToArray());
                }

            }
            else
            {
                entries.Add(entry.FullName, new byte[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////
    // STEP 2: BUILD ZIP FILE
    ///////////////////////////
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var newArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var uncompressedEntry in entries)
        {
            var newEntry = newArchive.CreateEntry(uncompressedEntry.Key, newCompressionLevel);
            using (var entryStream = newEntry.Open())
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(entryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(uncompressedEntry.Value);
            }
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

At the end of the function if I do:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\test.zip", ms.ToArray());
```

It creates a correctly structure archive sized `90mb` but no files are extractable.

If I end with `return ms.ToArray()` it returns a `~130kb` byte array.

Comment: Well the long way around would be to extract the first archive to a temp location and re-compress it into the new archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip archive is broken because you read its content from `MemoryStream` before it is finished. In order to finish archive creation you need to call [`newArchive.Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh158289(v=vs.110).aspx) before calling `ms.ToArray()`.
In this particular case you can do it like this:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var newArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var uncompressedEntry in entries)
        {
            var newEntry = newArchive.CreateEntry(uncompressedEntry.Key, newCompressionLevel);
            using (var entryStream = newEntry.Open())
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(entryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(uncompressedEntry.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```